# Request.UrlReferrer return error on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

I webpage show an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object', on this line :

```
prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

urlreferrer return null now.

this work fine before. Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it?

Comment: Put your code here......

Comment: prevPage =Convert.ToString(Request.UrlReferrer);

Answer (score 1):

`Request.UrlReferrer` only have value when some other page redirect to this page. If someone directly access your page this property will remain null.

Also UrlReferrer is based off the HTTP_REFERER header that a browser should send. But, because it is control by the browser there are ways to suppress this.

As far as i know "security" suites like Norton's Internet Security will strip that header, in the belief that it aids tracking user behavior. Also, some Firefox extensions to do the same thing.

Modified you code as below to make sure you will not get error

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
}
else
{
    //Alternate logic if UrlReferrer not found
}
```